# akka-http application running inside docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile, akka-http

I've got an akka-http application that works fine locally, I'm having some problems "dockerizing" the application. I build the docker image through the Dockerfile and using a docker-entrypoint to execute the java -jar command. When I firstly access the running docker container the app is not running although If I access the container and manually execute the java -jar command the app starts fine. If I execute the following command (inside the container) the application starts fine as well:

```
bash -xe docker-entrypoint.sh
```

See below my Dockerfile

```
FROM qa.stratio.com/stratio/ubuntu-base:16.04

MAINTAINER stratio

ARG VERSION

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y screen

COPY target/khermes-${VERSION}-allinone.jar /khermes.jar
COPY docker/docker-entrypoint.sh /
COPY src/main/resources/application.conf /

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

And see also below my docker-entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash -xe

java -jar -Dkhermes.client=false -Dakka.remote.hostname=localhost -
Dakka.remote.netty.tcp.port=2553 -Dakka.cluster.seed-
nodes.0=akka.tcp://khermes@localhost:2552 /khermes.jar

tail -f /dev/null
```

Does anyone have an idea on why my application is getting killed when I run the container?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [SBT Native Packager](http://sbt-native-packager.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) instead. My `build.scala` looks like this

```
import com.typesafe.sbt.packager.archetypes.JavaAppPackaging
import com.typesafe.sbt.packager.docker.{Cmd, DockerPlugin}
import com.typesafe.sbt.packager.docker.DockerPlugin.autoImport._
import sbt._
import Keys._

object build extends Build {

  lazy val root: Project = Project(
    id = "my-awesome-server",
    base = file("."),
    settings = Defaults.coreDefaultSettings ++ Seq(

      resolvers ++= {
        Seq(
          "sonatype snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
      },

      organization := "co.awesome-startup",
      version := "2.69",
      scalaVersion := "2.11.8",
      libraryDependencies ++= {
        Seq(
          "org.tpolecat" %% "atto-core"  % "0.4.2" withSources()
        )
      },
      dockerBaseImage := "expert/docker-java-minimal:server-jre",
      dockerCommands := dockerCommands.value.flatMap {
        case cmd@Cmd("FROM", _) => List(cmd, Cmd("RUN", "apk update && apk add bash"))
        case other => List(other)
      },
      dockerRepository := Some("awesome-startup"),
      version in Docker := version.value,

      scalacOptions := Seq("-unchecked", "-deprecation", "-encoding", "utf8", "-language:implicitConversions", "-language:postfixOps", "-language:higherKinds", "-Xcheckinit"), //, "-Xlog-implicits"),
      javaOptions in compile += "-g:source,lines,vars",
      crossPaths := false,
      mainClass in  Compile := Some("co.awesome-startup.server.EntryPoint")
    )
  ).enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging).
    enablePlugins(DockerPlugin)
}
```

You'll need to change name of project and `dockerRepository` to match your repo in Docker Hub and then you can build and deploy it by calling `sbt docker:publish`. If you want to publish Docker image locally call `sbt docker:publishLocal`